# RelativeLayout pushes centered View to right

Tags: android, android-layout

I hope you can help me since this is driving me nuts...

I have a simple `RelativeLayout` with two child Views as you can see in the code sample. The `TextView` should be **centered** and the `ProgressBar` **left aligned**.

In the layout editor this is rendered correctly, but on the device/emulator the `TextView` gets pushed to the right and also the `ProgressBar` has a random offset.

You can ignore the fact that the text and button color is different, I already checked that that doesn't make any difference.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popup_redeem_button"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_outer"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rounded_yellow"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.fireflow.milebox.ui.views.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_redeem_text"
        style="@style/ButtonHeadlineMenu_Font"
        app:richText="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:text="@string/voucher_redeem"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Shape for the button background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
     android:radius="6dp"
   />

   <solid
     android:color="@color/btn_yellow_pressed"
   />
</shape>
```

[image]

I don´t measure or change any layout bounds in code, so I really cannot think of the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the custom `TextView`'s `layout_width` to `"match_parent"`, and set its `gravity` to `center_horizontal`.

Comment: Thank you, this really fixed the issue. Easy but efficient :D. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Oh, neato! I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you try changing the custom `TextView`'s `layout_width` to `match_parent`, and setting its `gravity` to `center_horizontal`. This will stretch the `TextView` to cover its parent horizontally, and then it can take care of centering its own text in itself. Since you've the `ProgressBar` listed after the `TextView`, the z-ordering will be correct, and the `ProgressBar` will appear on top of the `TextView`.